# How to programmatically add a background to a pdf?

Tags: python, image, pdf, vector-graphics, inkscape

Given a `.pdf` file (produced by `Inkscape` with the `LaTeX` option, but I am more focused on the `.pdf`), is there a way to add programmatically a background (ideally, the background would be a rounded rectangle) to it? I am thinking typically of a `python` script or a `C`(or `objective-C`) library.

Typically:

[image]

I guess I should be easier to act directly (maybe via the command line) within `Inkscape`, but I am looking for a solution on the `.pdf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your background is also a PDF, you can use [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/):

cpdf -stamp-under stamp.pdf input.pdf -o out.pdf

Comment: Great!! Do you know how can I create a pdf whose content is only a rounded rectangle? That would make it. Thanks.

Comment: I know it's been ten years, but you could just inkscape to make the rectangle pdf right?

Answer (score 1):

Working further from the answer of johnwhitington I found, that qpdf allows for that as well with the "underlay" option:

```
qpdf --underlay "background.pdf" -- input.pdf output.pdf
```

Great advantage: qpdf is available in most distributions. And as allways you can look at `qpdf --help` to find even more options to specify the page or to work inplace i.e. no need to specify an output file.

Ghostscript and Imagemagick allow for the same, but I found it quite hard to have a proper solution and the .pdf will become a rasterized image.