# Use PDF as Background for another PDF PYTHON

Tags: python, pdf

I have two pdfs " **file.pdf** ; **BACKGROUND.pdf** ". i wanna use BACKGROUND.pdf as background for file.pdf with **python**.

i don't know where to start i'm a python developper beginner

Comment: Search for Python PDF libraries.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`qpdf --underlay "background.pdf" -- file.pdf output.pdf`

Should work for most cases.

Python users  can use https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf a wrapper around qpdf
documentation at https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
especially for this case [Overlays, underlays, watermarks, n-up](https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/overlays.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could convert your first PDF to an image using this :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-pdf-to-image-using-python/

```
# import module
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
 
 
# Store Pdf with convert_from_path function
images = convert_from_path('example.pdf')
 
for i in range(len(images)):
   
      # Save pages as images in the pdf
    images[i].save('page'+ str(i) +'.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Then use the image as background for the second file.

Or use another util :
[How to programmatically add a background to a pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22117734/how-to-programmatically-add-a-background-to-a-pdf)